# View document position window on right side in Atom editor like Sublime Text?

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-2, atom-editor

The title pretty much covers it. In [Atom](http://atom.io) can you display the position where you are in the current document like you can in [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)? An example of what I'm talking about can be seen on Sublime's homepage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you need the [atom-minimap](https://github.com/fundon/atom-minimap) package in order to get that feature